# Vue.js + Triggerring methods of the independent class does not work in html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have the below class. The functions of the class are not assigned to the data property 'this.gridFilter' when instantiated.
I am calling 'gridFilter.set' onclick of the list item which does not get triggered and I get the following error on the console 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_withTask')' and nothing works.
This happens only when I call the 'set' function from the instantiated object.
How can I call the class functions from the Html file? Please help

```
class GridFilters
{

    constructor(grid)
    {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.filterError = false;
        this.isShow = false;
        this.currentFilter = '';
        this.filters = {};
    }

    async loadFilters()
    {
        const query = `?$select=*&$filter=mastertable eq ${window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace(/[{}]/g, "")}&$orderby=ice_name asc`;
        this.filters = await window.parent.Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords('filters', query);
        return this.filters;
    }

    async set()
    {
        const grid = this.grid;
        grid.$refs.overlay.classList.remove('customgrid-modal-hidden');
        grid.$refs.filter.classList.remove('customgrid-modal-hidden');
    }

}


export default {
 data() {
  return {
  gridFilter : {};
  };
 },
methods: {},
created () {
this.gridFilter = new GridFilters(this); 
 }
 };
```

//html

```
<li><a v-on:click="gridFilter.set"><img src="../Images/ICE.Filter.svg" title="Filter" /><span>Filter</span></a></li>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, where `this.grid` come from?

Comment: @Mina Updated the code above. it is coming from created function and i missed to add that property while posting

Comment: But, I test it and it works fine. check this. https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-burnell-gcfizj

Comment: @Mina After adding round brackets in the function call it works. Instead of <a v-on:click="gridFilter.set"> i wrote it like this <a v-on:click="gridFilter.set()"> and it worked